# how to store a whole page code into a variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page called abc.php
in abc.php page there are some code with '@'
I want to fetch that code in CI controller and replace with a number.

for example:
`<section class="layout_section_@"></section>`, I want to load this code in controller and '`@`' replace with any number

Comment: can you show us an example?

Comment: abc.php ->    <section class="layout_section_@"></section>, I want to load this code in controller and '@' replace with any no

Comment: can't you do something like `<section class="layout_section_<?=$num?>"></section>` within a loop?

Comment: this is only a example, but i have almost 80 lines of code, how to do it?

Comment: and clientside? change the DOM with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: i did not get ur point

Comment: I'm asking if you may use a clientside scripting language?

Comment: okay thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to provide the dynamic data from the controller to the view.

Controller:

```
$this->load->view('viewname',array('num'=>12345));
```

View:

```
<section class="layout_section_<?php echo $num ?>"></section>
```

If you really want to stick to your plan you can also get the View as variable into the controller with that:

```
$viewHtml = $this->load->view('viewname','',TRUE);
echo str_replace('@','12345',$viewHtml);
```

But that's really bad practise

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, when you want load contents from view to controller you must push 3rd parameters = true.

this is an example:

```
$views_1 = $this->load->view('viewname1', [], true);
$views_2 = $this->load->view('viewname2', [], true);
```

for your problem. I suggest this:
pass data to view in 2nd parameter:

example:

viewname1.php

```
<div class="view"><?= $view_name ?></div>
```

and in the controller, pass the $view_name to view:

```
$view_1 = $this->load->view('viewname1', ['view_name' => 'this is view name 1'], true);
```